# Thesis Framework and Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-thesis-theme

First time creating/implementing custom post types in Thesis, not first time using custom post types.

I used the Reed Write plugin to create the custom post types.  The site is using Thesis 1.8.5.

On the following page (http://www.snyderleadership.com/press-releases/) I have the main content getting dropped in with the contents of the custom post type after it.

I used the custom_functions.php file to create a custom page template and call the db for the contents of the custom post type. Here is my code:

```
/* CUSTOM PRESS RELEASE TEMPLATE - ADDED by BRETT ATKIN */

function press_releases_page() {
if (is_page('press-releases') || is_page('583')) { ?>

<div id="content">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post_box">
    <div class="headline_area"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>
    <div class="format_text">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php
        $original_query = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;

        $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'press-release',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>
    <div id="press-releases">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="press-wrapper">
            <div id="press-image">
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_image', true)); ?>
            </div><!-- end press-image div -->
            <div id="press-information">
                <p class="press-date"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_date', true); ?></p>
                <p class="press-link"><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_link', true); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_title', true); ?></a></p>
                <p class="press-author"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_author', true); ?></p>
            </div><!-- end press-information div -->
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div><!-- end press-wrapper div -->
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div><!-- end press-releases div -->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- end content -->
    <?php echo thesis_sidebars(); ?>
<?php } }

add_action('thesis_hook_custom_template', 'press_releases_page');
```

It seems like everything is working correctly, just not pulling in the data for the custom post type.

Having done this on other sites (using custom themes), I'm not sure if I did something wrong here or if it is a Thesis issue.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Brett

Comment: I'm seeing something interesting happen here..... `<div id="press-releases">` does not seem to be executed. You're also missing a semicolon after your first `endif`

Comment: Yeah, not sure how the code doesn't through an error without that ;.  I have fixed it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final working code.  Thanks to the help from of a local WP Guru friend and maiorano84.  We didn't figure out the cause, but we did fine a solution.

```
function press_releases_page() {
if (is_page('press-releases') || is_page('583')) { ?>

<div id="content">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post_box">
    <div class="headline_area"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>
    <div class="format_text">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php
        $original_query = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;

        $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'press-release',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>

    <div id="press-releases">
        <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $results = get_post_custom(); ?>
        <div id="press-wrapper">
            <div id="press-image"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($results['release_image'][0] ); ?></div><!-- end press-image div -->
            <div id="press-information">
                <p class="press-date"><?php echo $results['release_date'][0] ?></p> 
                <p class="press-link"><a href="<?php echo $results['release_link'][0] ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $results['release_title'][0] ?></a></p>
                <p class="press-author"><?php echo $results['release_author'][0] ?></p>
            </div><!-- end press-information div -->
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div><!-- end press-wrapper div -->
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div><!-- end press-releases div -->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- end content -->
    <?php echo thesis_sidebars(); ?>
<?php } }

remove_action('thesis_hook_custom_template', 'thesis_custom_template_sample');
add_action('thesis_hook_custom_template', 'press_releases_page');
```

Comment: does this still apply to thesis 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
<div id="press-releases">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="press-wrapper">
```

To this:

```
<div id="press-releases">
<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<div id="press-wrapper">
```

**UPDATE:**

The only other thing I can see is that you're not resetting your post data, and that the $wp_query variable is actually a Wordpress Global. Try using the reset functions and changing your WP_Query instance name like this:

```
<?php
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $args = array (
    'post_type' => 'press-release',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>
<div id="press-releases">
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Now that you have your wrappers being written to your document, you need to normalize your information. Try to avoid using Metadata instead of normal post attributes. I imagine your metadata 'release_image' is a link to an image somewhere on your server:

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>
    <div id="press-wrapper">
        <div id="press-image">
            <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'release_image', true); ?>" />
        </div><!-- end press-image div -->
        <div id="press-information">
            <p class="press-date"><?php echo the_date(); ?></p>
            <p class="press-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            <p class="press-author"><?php the_author(); ?></p>
        </div><!-- end press-information div -->
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div><!-- end press-wrapper div -->
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Comment: No dice either...thanks for trying.  This code works on other sites (that doesn't mean it is 100& correct though).  The only new variable is Thesis.  Here is another example (different cpt) on the same site. http://www.snyderleadership.com/speaking/  Is it odd that no errors are getting generated.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. The only oddity about this is that Thesis has its own custom hooks for template registration, so you end up having to wrap your template in a function. What happens when you `var_dump($query);`? Can you update with the output?

Comment: I put it after the $wp_query = new WP_Query($args); and got NULL

Comment: You need to change $wp_query to just $query and `var_dump($query)`.

Comment: Yep, sorry.  It returned a bunch of stuff.  Check it out.  http://www.snyderleadership.com/press-releases/ In all this junk are the values of the posts for that post type

Comment: Good. Take out the var_dump, and make sure that the variable is no longer called $wp_query. Use the code EXACTLY as I've written it in my update.

Comment: Replaced everything and no output.  I threw back in the var_dump and it spits out the junk.  I added a second Press Release.  It is looping through the posts and outputting code for two posts.  Wonder if I have to use something besides get_post_meta

Comment: That's exactly the problem. You ARE getting output for two posts (two press-release wrappers are now being written to your document) but your key information is missing. Give me a few moments.

Comment: I really appreciate your help here.

Comment: @Brett Review the update. That should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, this outputs the post data.  The link it generates goes to the actual post page were the custom fields I created are getting outputted.  The release image is one of those custom fields.  It is an image uploaded in the Media section and linked to.  I'm sorry, not sure where I'm supposed to go with this.  Are you saying I shouldn't be using get_post_meta?

Comment: I would say to avoid it as much as possible in favor of the built-in Wordpress Functions. Now that your posts are being written to the Page, if you need any help with outputting certain fields of information, please mark this as answered and open a new question. In the meantime I'm off to bed. I'll keep on the lookout for any new questions you might have.

Comment: get_post_meta isn't a built-in WP function?  This must be something with Thesis because I've used this exact code on many other sites

Comment: No, get_post_meta IS built-in, but you're using it to grab information which is already a part of posts, which is a no-no.

Comment: Huh?  I created a custom post type and that custom post type has custom fields (press-date, press-image, press-link and press-author) outside the standard post data like title, content, author, date, etc..

Comment: Ahhhh, NOW I see what that information is. I was under the impression that press-date === post-date, etc. That's fine. get_post_meta is fine for that.